# Programmatic configuration of Apache Commons Logging

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons-logging

I want to include an external library in my Java project, and this library in particular uses Apache Commons Logging to write messages to the logging system. The library writes a lot of messages of level "info", causing a lot of useless entries in the logs.

My application is supposed to be deployed and executed in a shared environment (for example, tomcat or jetty). My question is, what options do I have to configure the log level for this library if I cannot rely on properties/xml configuration files?

Comment: And why can't you user properties or xml configuration?

Comment: My application is part of a larger platform. Is supposed to get the log system from a log server, adjust to the rules and not cause any trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Apache Commons Logging is not really a logging library, it's just a facade that delegates to the underlying logging library like Log4J or `java.util.logging`. So first you have to discover which library are you *actually* using. Depending on that different configuration options apply.

My suggestion is to add replace `commons-logging.jar` with [SLF4J bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) and then use whichever framework you want.

Comment: I suggest looking at LogBack for the SLF4J implementation.

Comment: There is a mismatch between SLF4J and JCL. In JCL (and Log4J) the logged object is an java.lang.Object, but in SLF4J (and Logback) it is a java.lang.String. If he used JCL for passing objects to listeners, by using the SLF4J bridge he loses the objects (a String.valueOf() is called in the bridge).

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh: interesting, but isn't this what ultimately every logging framework has to do? I mean call `.toString()` on the object?

Comment: SLF4J bridge looks very promising, I'll try it and I'll be back to this forum to let you know.